# Eclipse's tab double click on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

On Eclipse, whenever I double click a tab, it fills the workspace (by hiding all other views like project tree, console, etc).

Is there any way to do this on Visual Studio?

Note: i'm not looking for full screen, just want a way to declutter the workspace but still have access to menus.

Comment: You can change explorers to autohide by pressing the pin button is that what your after?

Comment: @CodeMonkey That's not exactly what I want, as it has the usual delay for the views to appear and disappear.

Comment: I work on both Eclipse and VS 2010. This is the one single feature in Eclipse that I misses in Visual Studio 2010. What is so hard to implement this?

Comment: This feature is finally supported by Visual Studio 2013 (through plugin), checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19971442/193634

Comment: Google brings me here after searching There is an extension what makes that, [**Double-Click Maximize (Microsoft DevLabs)**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.Double-ClickMaximize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you after [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/01/16/did-you-know-you-can-auto-hide-all-of-your-tool-windows-with-one-command.aspx)?

Set shortcuts for the `Window.AutoHideAll` function and for the `Window.ResetWindowLayout` function. In order for the ResetWindowLayout to work, you have to export your settings (make sure you select "All Settings") with all windows expanded and then import them again.

ResetWindowLayout will restore all windows to the way they were the last time you imported your settings.

Comment: Yes, it should be like this, but without the hiding delay... Besides, how do I get all tools to show up again?

Comment: Added the bit about getting windows to show up again to the answer. Can't help with the delay, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Not with double click on tab, but you can do the same with Shift+Alt+Enter key combination.

This keyboard shorcut was changed to F11 from 1.9.1 vscode version.

All keyboard Shortcuts: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that, as well, and I now just got used to using full screen (Shift+Alt+Enter), which hides a little too much, which you seem to think, as well, but does in fact still show the menus.

Comment: Indeed menus are shown, but it still doesn't behave like Eclipse's double click tab feature...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like drby got it on this one.  Just FYI.  I pinged the VS team to ask about this and here is the response:

"There is no way to reverse the command automatically. For it to work as a toggle we would need to save which toolwindows were auto hidden and which ones were not when the command was run, which we don’t do (it would cause lots of interesting persistence questions, across profiles and VS sessions)."

The idea of a "Unhide All" command is what I suggested.  So if you hide all then you can unhide all as well.  There might be some windows you don't want to unhide but the 1 or 2 extra windows is better than not having an unhide IMHO.

Comment: Oddly enough though. You can do this with a macro. I used a code sample off MSDN.  I think it saves the layout somewhere in the registry and just pulls them out by name.