# How to disable Eclipse's behavior of maximizing editor when double clicking a tab?

Tags: eclipse

I recently updated my Eclipse (now running 20100218-1602), and I've found whenever I click around quickly between tabs on the tab bar, it will sometimes maximize the editor and hide the PHP Explorer to the left.  After researching a little, this appears to be a feature of double clicking a tab.  So I guess it's my fault, I'm sure I'm clicking around too fast and mistakenly double clicking a tab, but it happens often enough on what I'd consider a normal editing session that I've come to absolutely loathe it, and even after the usual googling due diligence cannot figure out how to turn it off.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594659/eclipses-tab-double-click-on-visual-studio) someone mentions the Window.AutoHideAll shortcut, however that seems to only be for assigning keyboard shortcuts--this is a mouse click thing.  But maybe it's a clue.

I can't find anything relevant under Eclipse -> Preferences -> PHP.  I don't think it's specific to PHP because if I switch to the Java perspective, double clicking a tab hides the Package Explorer.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This feature drives me nuts.  I don't need the tab-maximize because I have huge multi-monitors but the slightest double click makes me have to reposition windows all the time.  Almost makes me want to switch to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could settle for a simpler solution than some arcane settings or shortcut:

1. resize your Eclipse main windows a bit smaller
2. drag the views you do not want to be covered after a "tab double-click" *outside* the main Eclipse window
3. there is no 3.

When you double-click, the Editor will cover only the main Eclipse window, while the other views will still be visible just beside that window.

Comment: Neat idea.  I was concerned this wouldn't work well with Expose (i.e. picking the big eclipse window wouldn't foreground them both) but in fact it does.